# functional dependency for mysql

Tags: mysql, database

How to use functional dependency in mysql?
I saw many cases are using it by select statement, buy my question is if it is possiable to create a functional dependency to a table?

eg.

```
CREATE TABLE MyGuests (
  id INT(6) UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
  firstname VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
  lastname VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
  fullname VARCHAR(60) fd(firstname lastname),
  email VARCHAR(50),
  reg_date TIMESTAMP
)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't create a synthetic column like that within a table.

You can do it with a view:

```
CREATE VIEW MyGuestsView
SELECT id, firstname, lastname, CONCAT(firstname, lastname) AS fullname, email, reg_date
FROM MyGuests
```